# SQL Server - Query to calculate weighted average based on last values for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have the following columns from a SQL table for Major League Baseball pitchers:

```
player_id   game_id             season_ip | season_whip |career_ip
```

And we have the following data:

```
502190  2013/04/18/miamlb-cinmlb-1  19      1.32    504
502190  2013/04/19/miamlb-cinmlb-1  19      1.32    504
502190  2013/06/11/cinmlb-chnmlb-1  73      1.32    558
502190  2013/06/13/cinmlb-chnmlb-1  81      1.24    566
502190  2013/09/29/pitmlb-cinmlb-1  192     1.25    677
502190  2014/04/22/cinmlb-pitmlb-1  28      0.99    705
502190  2014/05/26/cinmlb-lanmlb-1  71      1.06    748
502190  2014/09/28/pitmlb-cinmlb-1  214     1.25    891
502190  2015/03/25/texmlb-cinmlb-1  14      0.71    891
502190  2015/08/15/wasmlb-sfnmlb-1  143     1.17    1034

453286  2013/05/05/detmlb-houmlb-1  39      1.04    844
453286  2013/05/16/detmlb-texmlb-1  54      0.99    859
453286  2013/09/29/detmlb-miamlb-1  214     0.97    1019
453286  2014/06/18/kcamlb-detmlb-1  98      1.25    1117
453286  2014/07/15/nasmlb-aasmlb-1  126     1.17    1145
453286  2014/09/28/minmlb-detmlb-1  220     1.18    1239
453286  2015/03/22/wasmlb-detmlb-1  14      0.93    1239
453286  2015/08/15/wasmlb-sfnmlb-1  165     0.9     1404
```

I need a SQL query to get the weighted average of the `season_whip` for each `player_id` based on the `season_ip` (innings pitched).
I only want to use the last entry for each year (note that the `game_id` column contains the year). So for `player_id` 502190, the last entry for the year 2015 is `game_id` `2015/08/15/wasmlb-sfnmlb-1`, year 2014 is `game_id` `2014/09/28/pitmlb-cinmlb-1`.

The formula is for weighted average is:

```
sum(season_ip * season_whip) / sum(season_ip)
```

So, for example, `player_id` 502190, his whip is

```
[192 * 1.25 + 214 * 1.25 + 143 * 1.17] / [192 + 214 + 143] = 1.229
```

I included `career_ip` because it's the only value that will increase over the span of all the years.  The `season_ip` resets each year and the `season_whip` varies throughout the year.

Any help is appreciated.  I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: why you use `192.1` and `214.1`? ... those are not the value in your sample data. In your data those are integers

Comment: I don't understand why you include `career_ip`, that value isn't used to calculate the weighted average. Also next time try to provide the sqlFiddle, that will help a lot.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I modified 192.1 to 192 and 214.1 to 214 to make it more clear in the table.  I forgot to modify the whip calculation.  I'll update it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e7a7e/30)

```
With whip as (
    SELECT *, SUBSTRING(game_id, 1, 4) as year_id
    FROM testMLB
),
year_whip as (
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, year_id ORDER BY game_id DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM whip
)
SELECT 
    player_id, 
    SUM(season_ip * season_whip) / sum(season_ip) 
FROM year_whip
WHERE RowNumber = 1
GROUP BY player_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get the last row per year for each player, and then group those rows in order to get the adjusted weighting for a player's whip. If so, you can use `row_number()` to only get the last row per player per year before grouping for the weighted average:

```
  select player_id, sum(season_ip * season_whip) / sum(season_ip) 
  from (
    select * ,
      row_number() over (partition by player_id, left(game_id,4) order by game_id desc) rn 
    from
    mytable
  ) t1 where rn = 1
  group by player_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17724/1

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This answer worked in sqlfiddle for the data set I provided, but for some reason it's not working on my full data set in SQL.  I'm not sure what's going on.  The answer by Juan Carlos Oropeza worked though, so I'll stick with that one.

Comment: @bbgoldm Maybe you should doble check or provide a bigger sample. Because our solutions are almost the same.